# How to access CFDictionary in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, core-foundation

I need to read and write some data from `CFDictionary` instances (to read and update EXIF data in photos). For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this in Swift 3. The signature for the call I want is:

```
func CFDictionaryGetValue(CFDictionary!, UnsafeRawPointer!)
```

How the heck do I convert my key (a string) to an `UnsafeRawPointer` so I can pass it to this call?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't have to deal with other Core Foundation functions expecting an `CFDictionary`, you can simplify it by converting to Swift native `Dictionary`:

```
if let dict = cfDict as? [String: AnyObject] {
    print(dict["key"])
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus, Swift imports `NSDictionary` as `[AnyHashable: Any]`, but that does not mean, `NSDictionary` is not convertible to `[String: AnyObject]`.

Comment: Watch out for performance issues on this - casting a CFDictionary to a Swift Dictionary is an expensive operation. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625787/225810

Answer (score 13):

Be careful converting a `CFDictionary` to a Swift native dictionary. The bridging is actually quite expensive as I just found out in my own code (yay for profiling!), so if it's being called quite a lot (as it was for me) this can become a big issue.

Remember that `CFDictionary` is *toll-free bridged* with `NSDictionary`. So, the fastest thing you can do looks more like this:

```
let cfDictionary: CFDictionary = <code that returns CFDictionary>
if let someValue = (cfDictionary as NSDictionary)["some key"] as? TargetType {
    // do stuff with someValue
}
```

Comment: "The bridging is actually quite expensive" - is it still the case in Swift 5.9 in 2023?

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
var key = "myKey"
let value = withUnsafePointer(to: &key){ upKey in
    return CFDictionaryGetValue(myCFDictionary, upKey)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write something like this:

```
let key = "some key" as NSString
if let rawResult = CFDictionaryGetValue(cfDictionary, Unmanaged.passUnretained(key).toOpaque()) {
    let result = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(rawResult).takeUnretainedValue()
    print(result)
}
```

But I guess you would not like to write such thing at any time you retrieve some data from that `CFDictionary`. You better convert it to Swift `Dictionary` as suggested in Code Different's answer.