# CFDictionary get Value for Key in Swift3

Tags: swift, cfdictionary

I've a problem with accessing a specific (or any) key in a CFDictionary. 
Honestly I don't really get the way you need to do this in Swift and I think it's overly complicated...

My Code:

```
if let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault) {
let mountedVolumes = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: [], options: [])!
for volume in mountedVolumes {
    if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volume as CFURL) {
        let diskinfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);   

        var volumeValue = CFDictionaryGetValue(diskinfo, <#T##key: UnsafeRawPointer!##UnsafeRawPointer!#>)


    }
}
```

What I want to achieve: Get the Value for the Key or field *DAVolumeNetwork* into the variable *volumeValue*.
I guess I need to pass the *kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey* to the *CFDictionaryGetValue* Method? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `CFDictionary` in Swift. (It is possible, but not worth the effort, see below.)

- `CFDictionary` is toll-free
  bridged with `NSDictionary`, which in turn can be cast  to a Swift `Dictionary`.
- The value of the `kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey` key is a
  `CFBoolean` which can be cast to a Swift `Bool`.

Example:

```
if let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault),
    let mountedVolumes = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: []) {
    for volume in mountedVolumes {
        if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volume as CFURL),
            let diskinfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk) as? [NSString: Any] {

            if let networkValue = diskinfo[kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey] as? Bool {
                print(networkValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness: This is the necessary pointer
juggling to call `CFDictionaryGetValue` in Swift 3:

```
if let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault),
    let mountedVolumes = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: []) {
    for volume in mountedVolumes {
        if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volume as CFURL),
            let diskinfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk) {

            if let ptr = CFDictionaryGetValue(diskinfo, Unmanaged.passUnretained(kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey).toOpaque()) {
                let networkValue = Unmanaged<NSNumber>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
                print(networkValue.boolValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and code! I still don't really get the CFDictionary but it's good if it can be cast in something useful :)

Comment: @nja: CFDictionary uses a C API, passing void pointers around. In (Objective-)C you can simply pass an object pointer for a void pointer and vice versa. You cannot do that in Swift and have to use the Unmanaged type instead, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift.

Comment: CFDictionary is toll-free bridged with NSDictionary, and this is the easiest/most performant way to get values out in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625787/225810

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `CFDictionaryRef` to a Swift dictionary:

```
if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volume as CFURL), let diskinfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk) as? [String: AnyObject] {
}
```

and then cast `kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey` to a Swift string:

```
var volumeValue = diskinfo[kDADiskDescriptionVolumeNetworkKey as String]
```

Comment: Casting a CFDictionary to Swift dictionary is expensive (not toll-free bridged). Best to cast to NSDictionary and use that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625787/225810